# access to downloads folder in phone in c language

Tags: java, android, c

I need in c language to get to a folder like Downloads 
this is  my path to Download folder :
/run/user/1002/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C022%5D/אחסון פנימי/Download

I have the code in java(that work)is but don't know how to do that in c:

```
 File root2 = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File sdcard = new File(root2.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
 sdcard.mkdirs();
 File file = new File(sdcard, "XYZ1.txt");
 if (!file.exists()) {
     try {
           file.createNewFile();
     }catch (IOException e) {

     }
 }
```

I would like to know how to get to Downloads folder in c language
tnx for help

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ask a specific question about some technical things, "how to do that" is very broad and unlikely to help other people who use StackOverflow.

Comment: The code shown its in java i need it in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent C code for the above would be something like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  FILE *fp = fopen("<relative/absolute path>/XYZ1.txt", "ab+"); //This create file if not present
  if (fp==NULL){
    printf("Could not create file in loc ..");
  }
  ......
  // Do your stuff with the file
  ......
  fclose(fp); //Close the file before leaving
}
```

More on file IO and modes of file access [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)

Comment: <relative/absolute path> how do i get to downloads folder?

Comment: The path is something you have to know in advance. In your `Java` example the language did not give you the path to ext storage - it's the platform that gave you which is Android in your case. Unfortunately you can't code Android apps in C - so you have to put a const path or relative (to the loc of the executable object file generated for this C code) your self at compile time